# react gets stuck after i resize the browser window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used react-simple-image-slider for image slider on my website, but after i resize the browser window the application gets stucked.

The main Aim is to make the react-simple-image-slider responsive.

**The below is the code.**

```
import './App.css';
import {useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SimpleImageSlider from 'react-simple-image-slider';

function App() { 
  const [widthAndHeight, setwidthAndHeight] = useState([window.innerWidth, 600]);
  
  useLayoutEffect ( ()=>
  {
    function updateTheWidthAndHeight()
    {
      setwidthAndHeight([window.innerWidth, 600]);
      
    }
      window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
      updateTheWidthAndHeight();
    })
  })

  const images = [
    { url: "logos/ethiopia.png" },
    { url: "logos/favicon.ico" },
    { url: "logos/gear.png" },
    { url: "logos/gear.jpg" }
  ];


  return (
      <div>
            <SimpleImageSlider
                style={{ margin: '0 auto', marginTop: '0px'}}
                className="slider"
                width={widthAndHeight[0]}
                height={widthAndHeight[1]}
                slideDuration={1}
                loop={true}
                autoPlay={true}
                images={images}
                showBullets={false}
                showNavs={true}
            />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a dependency list for `useLayoutEffect` so it's adding an event listener on every render. Add an empty list for one-time execution:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  function updateTheWidthAndHeight() {
    setwidthAndHeight([window.innerWidth, 600]);
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    updateTheWidthAndHeight();
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: have you ever used react-simple-slider-image ? is this code safe to make it responsive ? i searched over the internet but i found nothing to customize it's style. i can change any style with not flaw but when i change it's height and width the slider changed to black background.

Comment: @gsharew Sorry, I don't have experience with react-simple-slider-image. There is react-responsive-carousel which is more popular.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect`. 
Maybe it will cause blocking visual updates.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Hope this might help you.